# Javascript - click event not returning object

Tags: javascript

So clicking the link here will write `javascript: void(0)` instead of the object reference for the "a" element, what is going on? What can I put in href that will do the same thing i.e not scroll the page like # does but write out the reference correctly?

```js
var el = document.getElementById("click");
el.addEventListener("click", (function(el) {
  document.write(el);
}).bind(this, el), false);
```

```html
<a id="click" href="javascript: void(0)">click</a>
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what result you expect from passing a DOM element to `document.write`. `document.write` expects a string containing HTML. What do you think an "object reference" looks like?

Comment: It should print the object reference if it was a div it would print [object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: Why are you using .bind??? makes no sense,  and you should not be using document.write. Use console.log() to debug, not document.write.

Comment: This is test code don't worry about what is it's supposed to do

Comment: `This is test code don't worry about what is it's supposed to do` Is a **poor** way to ask for help

Comment: Seems like `HTMLAnchorElement`s overwrite `toString`. You can always do `Object.prototype.toString.call(object)` to get the default `toString` behavior.

Comment: So the real question is how can you have a link with href="#" and not scroll the page when it is clicked?

Comment: No using # also doe not return the object, it returns the contents of the href attribute.

Comment: Of course it does. Stringifying an `<a>` element returns the value of its `href` attribute. That behavior is always the same,  no matter the value of that attribute.

Comment: @zak not if you concentrate on the question and not what the code may or may not be doing in when not trimmed down for testing.

Comment: So is the question really "how to get the default string representation of an object" ?

Comment: I need to access the variable "el" in the anonymous function as a DOM object reference i.e the whole "a" tag not the contents of href attribute.

Comment: `el` **is** the whole element. You are seeing only the value of the `href` tag because that what happens when `el.toString()` is called, which gets called because you pass `el` to `document.write`. So yes, it is important to explain what you are actually trying to do because then we could sorted this out much quicker: `document.write` is not a debugging tool. Use `console.log` or `console.dir` to inspect the value of a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.write()` needs to convert its argument to a string in order to write it, so it calls `el.toString()`. `HTMLAnchorElement` overrides the default method and returns the `href` attribute.

You can bypass this by calling the `toString()` function of the `HTMLElement` prototype object.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("click");
el.addEventListener("click", (function(el) {
  document.write(HTMLElement.prototype.toString.call(el));
}).bind(this, el), false);
```

```html
<a id="click" href="javascript: void(0)">click</a>
```

Comment: I'm confused why you have to do this for an A tag and not a DIV?

Comment: Because `HTMLAnchorElement` has its own `toString()` method that returns the `href`, which overrides the default behavior.

Comment: So when selecting an A object it will always return the HREF attribute and not the object? Weird.

Comment: @user1209203: No. **Calling the `toString()` method** will return the `href` value, which is what happens when you pass the DOM element to `document.write`.  `document.write` is not a debugging tool. Use `console.log` or `console.dir` to inspect the value of a variable.

Comment: And toString is called when calling document.write and console.log?

Comment: @user1209203 The argument to `document.write()` has to be a string. If it's not a string, it's converted to a string by calling the object's `toString()` method.

Comment: @user1209203 The argument to `console.log()` doesn't have to be a string, it can be any type of object. The console knows how to display all the detailed contents of objects.

Comment: @Felix Kling I was using console.log and the same thing was happening

Comment: @user1209203: Only when passed to `document.write`. There is no standard for `console.log` so it represents the passed in value however it wants.

Comment: Man what a pain in the ass.

Comment: @user1209203: It would have been easier if you explained from the beginning what you were actually trying to do. Again: `el` is a DOM element, no matter what kind of element you are selecting.

Comment: @user1209203: As for the output of `console.log`: It gives the `outerHTML` of the element in Chrome, so certainly different than what `document.write` produces.

Comment: But from console log it didn't look that way, which was very confusing I can tell you.

Comment: @user1209203: Which is why there is `console.dir` which is a better way to actually inspect an object.

Comment: @user1209203 Printing DOM elements in the document is not a common thing to do. This kind of stuff is normally done using the browser's Developer Tools interactively.

Comment: @user1209203: If you had explained your actually issue, i.e. something like *"I'm trying to select an `<a>` element with `getElementById ` but it looks like I'm only getting the value of its `href` attribute"* (plus the code of course) we could have quickly pointed out where your mistake is (which is how you expected the value, not how you got it). Instead we were confused why you want to see `[object HTMLAnchorElement]` and explained how you get it even though this is not the actual problem you had. Always explain your actual problem!

Comment: Well I didn't know what was going wrong, I thought the void command was causing the script to bug out.